# What exactly is on and off topic?

Tags: discussion

This has been confusing me for quite some time.

The [on/off topic list](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) seems quite clear. As a rough cut, professional networking, network design and protocols on topic, anything related to home networking off topic. In practice this seems to depend on ... what? How quickly it can be answered from the top of the head?

Examples from today:

["Hosting a website using dynamic public IP: What if the ISP did not assign any port forwarding?"](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76477/hosting-a-website-using-dynamic-public-ip-what-if-the-isp-did-not-assign-any-po) - in my eyes clearly a home networking question based already on the title, supported by OP:s opening sentence `"Let's just say that I am a peasant that can only avail of a typical Dynamic Public IP address from my ISP."` Answered, not directed to SuperUser.

["Proxying traffic from one VPN to another"](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76480/proxying-traffic-from-one-vpn-to-another) - in my eyes not nearly as clear-cut from the title, but first sentence `"I have a homelab running Debian."` puts it off topic. Not answered, directed to SuperUser.

Could the esteemed senior community members please clarify - is there an actual, common on/off -topic policy? If yes, when and how should it be applied?

Comment: It takes the users voting to close a question to get it closed, and that may not happen quickly. Both of those questions are now closed.

Comment: Ah. Doesn't really answer the question tho', "on topic" seems to often equate "this looks interesting". That's why I'm asking.

Comment: The SE recommendation is to close off-topic questions quickly, but it can happen more slowly in a small community, such as NE, and some users complain that it happens too quickly, especially for questions that can be rehabilitated, e.g. need more detail or clarity. We usually get around to closing the off-topic questions within a day. and it is based on the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, not that a question is simply interesting or not. In fact, there are many on-topic questions that languish (not interesting?).

Comment: Yeah, I know :-) I've seen those "this shouldn't have been closed" on Meta... a few came up as "related" when I was writing my question. And questions do languish, what's there to do, we're all volunteering our time and know-how here, there's no guarantee any question will ever be answered on any forum. Closure time is really not my point at all.

Comment: At least I'm not sure what your point is (and I'm honestly not trying to be snarky).  The criteria for what's on topic (or not) is pretty well agreed upon.  The enforcement of that criteria relies, in part, on the judgement of other users.  Some of these reviewers might immediately vote the question on topic.  Some might find it on the bubble and choose to leave it.  Others still might leave a comment as a quick courtesy while a few might think it's appropriate and answer it.  The order and rate with which these various folks encounter the question determines its destiny.  What's unclear?